# Does values of global variable changes if they are updated in function?

Tags: c, function, global-variables

actually i have written this code but it isnt working.help me plz.

```
unsigned short checkCollisionOrFood(unsigned short rowHead,unsigned short colHead)
/*this the functionother then main function where i am changing value of "rowHead",but on checking it remain same*/
{
if(turn==0){
    if(address[colHead]&(1<<((rowHead+1)%8))){
        if(((int)(address[(colHead+7)%8]&(1<<(rowHead+1)%8))
           +(int)(address[colHead]&    (1<<(rowHead+2)%8))
           +(int)(address[(colHead+1)%8]&(1<<(rowHead+1)%8)))>1) return -1;
        else{
            rowHead=(rowHead+1)%8;//this value of rowHead is not getting change.
            return 1;
            } 
        } 
    }
```

the variables "turn","rowHead","colHead" are global variables.
Now after modifying this code as per instruction of Daniel Fischer,it is

```
unsigned short checkCollisionOrFood()
{
if(turn==0){
    if(address[colHead]&(1<<((rowHead+1)%8))){
    if(((int)(address[(colHead+7)%8]&(1<<(rowHead+1)%8))
    +(int)(address[colHead]&(1<<(rowHead+2)%8))
    +(int)(address[(colHead+1)%8]&(1<<(rowHead+1)%8)))>1) return -1;
      else{
          rowHead=(rowHead+1)%8;
          return 1;
          } 
          }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function parameters

```
unsigned short checkCollisionOrFood(unsigned short rowHead,unsigned short colHead)
```

shadow the global (file scope, actually) variables of the same name, so in the function, you only change the copies of the passed arguments, that has no effect outside the function. In the function, you cannot access the shadowed global variables (without some gymnastics).

The point of global variables is that they (nor pointers to them) need not be passed as arguments, since they can be accessed without that.

Comment: Because you shadowed the names. Inside the function, the names refer to the arguments, not the global variables.

Comment: @shafeeq Don't argue with what Daniel Fischer says. He knows what he is talking about and he's right in this case. You have to make the effort understanding his explanation.

Comment: @DanielFischer now i have removed arguments still not working.

Comment: @shafeeq Then it seems your conditions are not what you expect them to be. Can you add your current code to the question?

Comment: @DanielFischer ques updated, what i want from this code is to change value of rowHead when i access it in main,but it is neither changing its value in main nor in function

Comment: @shafeeq I suspect your conditions are not what you think they are. The inner `if` condition is met whenever one of the bitwise ands gives a nonzero value, unless the modulus `(rowHead + x)%8` is zero (then the corresponding `&` would produce a 1). And what happens if `address[colHead]&(1<<((rowHead+1)%8))` is 0?

Comment: @DanielFischer can i contact you by your email or any other way?

Comment: We could create a chatroom here, @shafeeq.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32220/discussion-between-shafeeq-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 1):

When you pass variables to function, they are passed by value. That means, that the function has it's own copy of the variable and you can manipulate by variable without modifying initial variable, that was passed.

If you want to modify the value of the global variable, you should not have parameters with the same name or local variables. So, your function supposed to be:

```
unsigned short checkCollisionOrFood();
```